# Group different selection option dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure if this is a html or javascript tech.
I want to achieve like that, only show two select boxes,
once I clicked India, another select box will shows only Indiacities options  `name="listtwo" id="listtwo"`, if clicked US, shows us cities options.
Could someone please give an example. Many thanks

India
            US
            Germany

```
    <select name="listtwo" id="listtwo">
        <option value="Indiacity1">Indiacity1</option>
        <option value="Indiacity2">Indiacity1</option>
        <option value="Indiacity3">Indiacity1</option>
    </select>

  <select name="list3" id="list3">
        <option value="Germany1">Germany1</option>
        <option value="Germany2">Germany1</option>
        <option value="Germany3">Germany1</option>
    </select>

<select name="list4" id="list4">
        <option value="US1">US1</option>
        <option value="US2">US1</option>
        <option value="US3">US1</option>
    </select>​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="country-select">
    <option>--- Select One ---</option>
    <option value="us">US</option>
    <option value="germany">Germany</option>
</select>

<select id="us-select" class="sub-menu hide">
    <option value="austin">Austin</option>
</select>

<select id="germany-select" class="sub-menu hide">
    <option value="berlin">Berlin</option>
</select>​
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;            
}​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#country-select').change(function (e) {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
    if (selectedCountry) {
        $('#' + selectedCountry + '-select').show();
    }       
});​
```

And the Fiddle for anyone to check out: http://jsfiddle.net/RPWPZ/3/

Of course you would have to add all the items for India, and any other countries you'll be caring about.

Edit: if you want a country selected when the page loads, look at the changes in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RPWPZ/5/

Comment: Thanks again. and how to show two options? always two option boxes show up on the page.

Comment: So will you have a default country selected when the page loads?  I added that `--- Select One ---` in there.  I'm going to modify my Fiddle real quick.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

  $('select').hide();
  $('#list2').show();

  $('.country').click(function(e) {
    $('select').hide();
    $('#'+$(e.target).attr('sel')).show();

  });
});
</script>


<a class="country" href="javascript:;" sel="list2">India</a>&nbsp;
<a class="country" href="javascript:;" sel="list3">Germany</a>&nbsp;
<a class="country" href="javascript:;" sel="list4">US</a>&nbsp;

<br><br>

<select name="list2" id="list2">
        <option value="Indiacity1">Indiacity1</option>
        <option value="Indiacity2">Indiacity1</option>
        <option value="Indiacity3">Indiacity1</option>
</select>

<select name="list3" id="list3">
        <option value="Germany1">Germany1</option>
        <option value="Germany2">Germany1</option>
        <option value="Germany3">Germany1</option>
</select>

<select name="list4" id="list4">
        <option value="US1">US1</option>
        <option value="US2">US1</option>
        <option value="US3">US1</option>
</select>
```